# Can't connect to SQL Server. Can't read Alias from SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-config-manager

I put the correct values in Aliases (SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration 32bit and 64bit) in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

When I try connecting to this database in SQL Server 2014, I get this error:

[image]

I'm putting the alias name in management studio.

Comment: can you connect through ipaddress and machine name?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu so I can connect using something like "RTYRTYRTYY1111\SQLXXX" as it's servername in the management studio. However when I put that same thing in the configuration manager and name an alias for that, the management studio will not recognize the alias name